# Show that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(1 + \tan^4 x) \cos^2 x \, dx = \frac{\pi \log(6 + 4\sqrt{2})}{4} - \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Show that $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(1 + \tan^4 x) \cos^2 x \, dx = \frac{\pi \log(6 + 4\sqrt{2})}{4} - \frac{\pi}{2}$$

**My try :**
$$\Omega = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(1 + \tan^4 x) \cos^2 x \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1 + x^4)}{(1 + x^2)^2} \, dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 \left\{ \log(1 + x^4) - 4 \log(x) \right\}}{(1 + x^2)^2} \, dx$$

$$2\Omega = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx - 4 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 \log(x)}{(1 + x^2)^2} \, dx$$

$$\Omega = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(1 + \tan^4 x) \, dx + 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{(1 + x^2)^2} \, dx$$

Comment: You could write the result of your integral in a easier way, that is, $\;\dfrac\pi2\log\left(2+\sqrt2\right)-\dfrac\pi2\,.\;$

Comment: For the latter remaining integral, consider substituting $x\mapsto\frac1x$ over $[1,\infty)$ and exploiting Taylor series.

Comment: Concerning the other integral, it results that $$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln\left(1+\tan^4\!x\right)\,\mathrm dx=\pi\ln\left(2+\sqrt2\right)\,.\;$$

Comment: Just today I posted a similar integral if you're interested ahaha (but there is no cosine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize
$$\frac1{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac12\left(\frac x{x^2+1}\right)’+\frac12\frac1{x^2+1}
$$
to continue with

\begin{align}
\Omega = &\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1 + x^4)}{(1 + x^2)^2} \, dx\\
\overset{ibp}=&-2\int_0^\infty \frac{x^4}{(x^4+1)(x^2+1)}dx+ 
\frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x^4+1)}{x^2+1}dx
\end{align}
where
$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^4}{(x^4+1)(x^2+1)}dx\overset{x\to \frac1x}=\frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx =\frac\pi4$ and
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln (x^4+1)}{x^2+1} d x \\
=&\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln (x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)+\ln(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)}{x^2+1} d x \\
 =&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)}{x^2+1} \ d x\\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg( \int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{2x\cos t}{x^2+2x \sin t+1} dt+ {\ln (x^2+1)}\bigg) \frac{dx}{x^2+1}\\
 =& \int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{-\pi\sin t}{1+\cos t} dt\ + {2\pi}\ln2
=  \frac{\pi}2\ln \left(6+4\sqrt{2} \right) 
\end{align}
As a result
$$\Omega= \frac{\pi}4\ln(6 + 4\sqrt{2})- \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks alot sir

Answer (score 6):

Let
$$I=\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\ln(1+\tan^4x)\cos^2x\,dx$$
$$J=\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\ln(1+\tan^4x)\sin^2x\,dx$$
From [Quanto's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4838150/221315)
$$I+J=\pi\ln(2+\sqrt2)\tag1$$
On the other hand, by integration by parts $(IBP)$ we have
$$I-J=\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\ln(1+\tan^4x)\cos2x\,dx
\stackrel{IBP}{=}-4\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\frac{\tan^4x}{1+\tan^4x}\,dx
\\=-2\pi+
\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^4x}\,dx
\\=-2\pi+\int_0^\infty\frac1{(u^4+1)(u^2+1)}du
\\\stackrel{RT}{=}-2\pi+\pi=-\pi\tag2$$
where $RT$ stands for Residue theorem. From $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$I=\frac{\ln(2+\sqrt2)\pi}2-\frac\pi 2.$$

Comment: Thanks alot sir

Answer (score 4):

If you are allowed to use complex numbers, this is pretty nice.

---

> **Lemma**. For $\alpha \in \mathbb C$, $\Re\alpha>0$, we have $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin^2 x + \alpha^2\cos^2x)dx = \pi \cdot \log\left(\frac{1+ \alpha}{2}\right).$$

(Proof below.)

---

If you perform the change of variable $x\mapsto \pi/2-x$ your integral becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I &=& \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2x \log(1+\tan^4x)dx=\\
&=&\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2x \log\left(1+\frac1{\tan^4x}\right)dx=\\
&=&\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2x\log(1+\tan^4x)dx-\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2x\log(\tan^4x)dx=\\
&=&\int_0^1\log(1+\tan^4x)dx - \mathcal I - 4\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2 \log (\tan x)dx.
\end{eqnarray}
From the above equation we get
\begin{eqnarray}\mathcal I &=& \frac12 \int_0^{\pi/2}\log(1+\tan^4x)dx - 2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2x\log (\tan x)dx=\\
&=&\frac12\underbrace{ \int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin^4x + \cos^4x) dx}_{\mathcal A} +\\
&&-\frac12 \underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos^4x)dx}_{\mathcal B} - 2\underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2x\log (\tan x)dx}_{\mathcal C}
\end{eqnarray}
For $\mathcal A$ we can use the **Lemma** to get
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal A &=& 2\Re\left\{ \int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin^2x + i\cos^2x)dx\right\}=\\
&=&2\Re\pi \log\left(\frac{\sqrt 2 + 1+i}{2\sqrt 2}\right)=\\
&=&2\pi \log\left|\frac{\sqrt 2 + 1+i}{2\sqrt 2}\right|=\\
&=& \pi \log\left(\frac{2+\sqrt 2}4\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Integral $\mathcal B$ is a classical result
$$\mathcal B =  4\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos x) = -2\pi\log2.$$
As for $\mathcal C$, perform the change of variable $x\mapsto \pi/2-x$ to obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal C &=& \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2x \log(\tan x)dx = \\
&=& -\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2x \log(\tan x)dx,
\end{eqnarray}
So that
\begin{eqnarray}\mathcal C &=&-\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos2x \log(\tan x)dx= \\
&\stackrel{IBP}{=}&\frac14\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin2x \cdot \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\cdot \frac1{\cos^2x}dx=\frac{\pi}4.
\end{eqnarray}
In the end, letting $\mathcal I = \frac12\mathcal A - \frac12\mathcal B -2\mathcal C$ yields
$$\boxed{\mathcal I = \frac{\pi}2\log(2+\sqrt 2) -\frac{\pi}2}.$$

---

*Proof of the Lemma*

Let
$$\mathcal J(\alpha) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin^2 x + \alpha^2\cos^2x)dx,$$
where $\alpha = r\cdot e^{i\theta}$, with $-\frac{\pi}2<\theta< \frac{\pi}2$. Observe that, if $\omega = \rho \cdot e^{i\theta}$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^r\frac{2\omega e^{i\theta} \cos^2x}{\sin^2 x+ \omega^2\cos^2x}d\rho &=& \log(\sin^2x + \alpha^2\cos^2x) - \log(\sin^2x),
\end{eqnarray}
so that
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal J(\alpha) &=& \underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^r \frac{2\omega e^{i\theta}\cos^2x}{\sin^2 x+ \omega^2\cos^2x}d\rho dx}_{\mathcal H(\alpha)} +\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin^2x)dx=\\
&=& \mathcal H(\alpha) - \pi \log 2.\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
We rewrite $\mathcal H(\alpha)$ as follows.
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal H(\alpha) &=& \int_0^r 2\omega e^{i\theta}\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{\omega^2+t^2}\cdot \frac1{1+t^2}dt d\rho=\\
&=&\int_0^r\frac{2\omega e^{i\theta}}{1-\omega^2}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{\omega^2+t^2}-\frac1{1+t^2}\right)dt d\rho=\\
&=& \int_0^1\frac{2\omega e^{i\theta}}{1-\omega^2}\left[\frac1{\omega}\arctan\left(\frac{t}{\omega}\right) - \arctan t\right]_0^\infty d\rho=\\
&=&\frac{\pi}2\int_0^r\frac{2\omega e^{i\theta}}{1-\omega^2}\left(\frac1{\omega}-1\right)d\rho=\\
&=& \pi\int_0^r\frac{e^{i\theta}}{1+\omega}d\rho=\pi\log(1+\alpha).
\end{eqnarray}
Use this result in \eqref{1} to prove the Lemma.

Comment: More than elegant